# Why is there widespread support for suspending Freedom of Assembly during the pandemic, but not for suppressing privacy?

Tags: united-states, covid-19, privacy

Pretty much every news outlet in the US these days supports the lockdowns despite them violating the First Amendment - from CNN to Fox News. Everyone seems to agree that lockdowns are inevitable, even if there are slight disagreements over what their scope should be at a given point of time. However consensus is a lot murkier when it comes to suspending privacy. For example, discussions of the recent Apple/Google contact tracing initiative all [mention privacy concerns](https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/11/21216803/apple-google-coronavirus-tracking-app-covid-bluetooth-secure):

> What if I don't want my phone to do this?
>
> Don’t install the app, and when the operating systems update over the summer, just leave the “contact tracing” setting toggled off. Apple and Google insist that participation is voluntary, and unless you take proactive steps to participate in contact tracing, you should be able to use your phone without getting involved at all.

And security experts are generally [opposed to the idea](https://threatpost.com/apple-google-coronavirus-tracking-privacy-fears/154689/):

> Despite Apple and Google’s emphasis on privacy, some remain concerned
> about its implications – particularly with the collecting and handling
> of sensitive healthcare data.
>
> Sergio Caltagirone, vice president of threat intelligence at Dragos,
> for instance outlined his concerns with the technology in a Twitter
> thread, calling it “literally a real-time walking health report.” He
> also worried that the data would be used to “discriminate against
> people, as fear of coronavirus will rise as we leave large-scale
> quarantine.”

So why are Americans wholeheartedly open to involuntary restrictions of their outdoor activities, but not open to restrictions on their privacy? Contact tracing cannot work efficiently unless most people have the app installed, so it would be paramount for everyone to have it on their phones - just like it is paramount for everyone to stay at home to minimize the number of infections. To expand the analogy:

1. Everyone must have the app -> everyone must stay home
2. The app must be on at all times -> you cannot go far even if you're going to a [deserted beach](https://oregonstateparks.org/index.cfm?do=v.dsp_featureArticle&articleId=272)
3. Such tracking doesn't violate the 4th amendment -> such lockdowns don't violate the 1st amendment
4. Those who fail to enable the app outside are punished -> those who go outside without an essential reason are punished
5. China has proven app based tracking works -> China has proven lockdowns work

Comment: +1 I'm not sure why people downvoted this question because it seems worded reasonably/neutrally enough, even though the answer may be somewhat obvious. (Clearly other countries e.g. SK have made different choices wrt to contact tracing... which also hints to the answer.)

Comment: Vote to close given current wording.  The primary goal of such public health measures isn't to *"suppress"* freedom -- without public health, there will be no general freedom to "suppress".  Imagine a town meeting where the town hall catches on fire.  The meeting is suspended by the Fire Department not because the Fire Chief hates freedom, but because his duty is to save lives.

Comment: Of course it would be possible for a criminal to abuse or exploit such policies, (suppose a hired arsonist starts a fire to disrupt a town meeting whose outcome would not favor his sponsor), but this question currently fails to distinguish between necessary and abusive applications.

Comment: @agc yes, I get the idea. But if the Fire Chief can suspend the meeting, why can't he also demand that fire sensors are now installed in all buildings, so that the fire truck could arrive on time?

Comment: It might indeed be better to change the wording from "supress" to "suspend" in the title, just to appease question critics on this this.

Comment: @Fizz: In my case, it was downvoted primarily because of the false statement that various social distancing measures are a violation of the First Amendment.  As a secondary point, the cell phone system knows where your phone is whenever it's turned on, so that's a violation of privacy right there.

Comment: Further, WRT the First Amendment's right to PEACEABLY assemble (emphasis mine), if by assembling people are going to infect others with a serious and potentally fatal disease, the assembly is no more peaceful than if they'd gotten together and started randomly shooting off their AR-14s.

Comment: @jamesqf doesn't that same logical path apply to contact tracing? If by not enabling it, they are going to walk around infecting others and providing no way of finding those others... Contact tracing is just distributed assembly.

Comment: @jamesqf by that logic mandatory contact tracing apps don't violate the 4th amendment as you don't have the right to hide your movement history if you're going around infecting others with a fatal disease.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Of course that would 1) assume that you're actually going around to such places; 2) that you have a device capable of running those particular apps.  Also, if the voluntary contact tracing is a violation of the 4th Amendment, then why is the ordinary collection of location data (without which the cell system can't function) not likewise a violation?  Could it be that by carrying a phone, you've implicitly consented to such collection?  Likewise, haven't  you given consent by installing a contact tracing app?

Comment: @jamesqf I'm speaking of a situation where the government mandates that everyone who leaves their home has a mobile phone with the app installed (presume financial help for those who cannot afford it) and where those who refuse are fined or jailed - full equivalent to the ban on free movement. I imagine police in plainclothes will be going around town and checking if people emit their beacon - if not they're getting a fine.

Comment: @JonathanReez: So you're creating a straw man, since AFAIK no one is actually suggesting anything like that?

Comment: @jamesqf no one suggesting that in the West because even non invasive tracking is met with skepticism - hence my question. In China it's already implemented and it's working. I really don't get why the 4th amendment gets more respect than the 1st amendment in a pandemic.

Comment: Imposing a lock-down reduces the number of contacts between people, thus reducing the spread of the virus. Contact tracing only tells you, which people to send into quarantine, with a lag-time of days (if meet you today, got infected yesterday and develop symptons a week after our meeting, then the information is pretty old). So, lock-down and contact-tracing seem to be quite different tools in the fight against the pandemic. However, I am not sure, whether this affects the support of the measures.

Comment: On 2nd thought, maybe they are protesting the former too https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52894/in-kansas-do-judges-have-the-ultimate-say-in-public-health-matters-even-in-an

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/65630/why-is-there-so-much-reluctance-to-make-the-covid-vaccine-mandatory-for-adults

Answer (score 7):

I think the fears expressed by some human rights groups are that such invasive tracing mechanisms might be "here to stay" once implemented. In contrast, it's a lot easier to roll back public assembly bans (which essentially don't rely on any new infrastructure or mechanisms in their implementation) once a public health crisis passes. (I'll try to find some quotes in support.)

[For example](https://techcrunch.com/2020/04/06/eu-privacy-experts-push-a-decentralized-approach-to-covid-19-contacts-tracing/), some European proposals with regard to smart-phone-based contact tracing, differ from the simple [GPS phone tracking](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia_pacific/coronavirus-south-korea-tracking-apps/2020/03/13/2bed568e-5fac-11ea-ac50-18701e14e06d_story.html) implemented in South Korea. The Swiss proposal for example:

> “Our protocol is demonstrative of the fact that privacy-preserving approaches to proximity tracing are possible, and that countries or organisations do not need to accept methods that support risk and misuse,” writes professor Carmela Troncoso, of EPFL. “Where the law requires strict necessity and proportionality, and societal support is behind proximity tracing, this decentralized design provides an abuse-resistant way to carry it out.”

And Tech Crunch itself editorializes (a bit):

> What’s crystal clear right now, though, is that without a thoughtfully designed protocol that bakes in privacy by design contacts-tracing apps present a real risk to privacy — and, where they exist, to hard-won human rights.
>
> Torching rights in the name of combating COVID-19 is neither good nor necessary is the message from the group backing the DP-PPT protocol.

Comment: Re "here to stay", there is no reason a person actually HAS to carry a phone all the time, or keep that phone turned on.  I survived several decades without a cell phone, as did most people over 30 or so.

Comment: @jamesq although to actual engage in society in 2020 as opposed to 1990 a phone is significantly more important. Not just for social functions, but being contactable for business as well.

Comment: @Jontia: Perhaps in some lines of work, that's true.  But it's been at least a decade since I had to deal with work-related phone calls.  Email is so much easier.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is likely to be different for everyone who feels this way, but there are some differences that could explain the different attitudes:

**How essential are the measures to the goal?**

It is clear that to prevent people having contact with other people you need social distancing, and that is only possible if most people stay out of public spaces most of the time, and do not meet up in private spaces.  However, contact tracing has been used as a tool of disease management for much longer than people have had smart phones; therefore, these measures are not so obviously essential.  For example, [India](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01058-5) is using large scale in person contact tracing, with phone records as a secondary backup.

**Who is making the rules**

The government is requiring people to stay in their homes.  Many people trust the government.  Apple, and particularly Google, are in the business of selling people's data, and so elicit less trust when they ask for it.

**How are the measures implemented**

Even if we accept that smart phone based contact tracing is required,  there are decisions to be made about how this is implemented.  Methods that require location data to be held by a central authority, such as those in China and South Korea, require trust in a central authority.  Methods that require distribution of personally identifiable information to all contacts, such as that proposed by Apple and Google, require trust in those you contact.  This could be avoided, for example using cryptographic technologies to identify contacts rather than personally identifiable information.  The app could be released as open source, and available on open source platforms, allowing widespread validation of security claims.  [There are schemes](https://github.com/DP-3T) that try to address all these concerns, but those currently in place do not.

**Public Communication**

As the first major action taken by the state has been to implement social distancing rules, there has been an accompanying communication campaign. This has made it clear to many people how important this is.  There has not yet been such a campaign to explain the importance of contact tracing, and the added power that smart phone based tracing could bring.  If and when such a campaign is implemented, public opinion is likely to shift. (thanks divibisan).

Comment: So what you're saying is - everyone will be onboard if this was an executive order from the Governor rather than a Google initiative?

Comment: Not exactly, but more people would trust it if it was written and distributed by the Governor, and more people again if it had other safeguards that I detail.

Comment: There's been an extensive campaign to explain what social distancing is, how it works, and why it's necessary now. People understand it and, for the most part, recognize why it's important. There's been nothing similar with contact tracing. I'd bet that if trusted figures like Andrew Cuomo or Dr. Fauci explained why it was necessary, more people would accept contact tracing

Comment: "social distancing [...] is only possible if most people stay out of public spaces most of the time": to me, is not even clear that this is necessary (or proportionate) for a country with 34 inhabitants / km². But then I'm writing from a Land (state) in Germany (>200 inh./km²) where the official rule is social disancing means staying at least 1.5 m, preferrably 2 m away from people that do not belong to your household. I.e. if public areas are so crowded that you'd violate the distance rule, you cannot go there. If they are not, fine, go and get some sun in the park.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the idea that the "right to assemble" would somehow supersede the inalienable right (as identified in the Declaration of Independence, for one) of life, iteself, is not a given.

> "your right to swing your arm leaves off where my right not to have my nose struck begins." - John B Finch

It is very clear that gatherings can present a very direct risk to the health and welfare of others. The concept that someone with a transmittable contagion being allowed to be quarantined for the benefit of public health is not a novel or unheard of concept. Keep in mind, also that this is being done at the state level, not the federal, but the powers do exist in federal law -

> The federal government derives its authority for isolation and quarantine from the Commerce Clause of the U.S. Constitution.
>
> Under section 361 of the Public Health Service Act (42 U.S. Code § 264), the U.S. Secretary of Health and Human Services is authorized to take measures to prevent the entry and spread of communicable diseases from foreign countries into the United States and between states.

[CDC website: Legal Authorities for Quarantine and Isolation](https://www.cdc.gov/quarantine/aboutlawsregulationsquarantineisolation.html)

I think the reason why it passes Constitutional muster is that this isn't something that can be done willy-nilly - there generally has to be some sort of declaration of a public emergency, either federal, state or both, and the courts have repeatedly allowed suspension of Constitutional rights in formally declared emergency situations or times of war.

This in not only recognized nationally but in many nations and internationally -

> Under international law, rights and freedoms may be suspended during a state of emergency; for example, a government can detain persons and hold them without trial. All rights that can be derogated from are listed in the International Covenant for Civil and Political Rights. Non-derogable rights cannot be suspended. Non-derogable rights are listed in Article 4 of the ICCPR; they include right to life, the rights to freedom from arbitrary deprivation of liberty, slavery, torture, and ill-treatment.

A couple of key notes on that Wikipedia passage would be the "right to life," and "freedom from **arbitrary** deprivation of liberty."

[Wikipedia: State of Emergency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_emergency)

When people are frightened for their lives, they tend to give up certain freedoms more easily, right or wrong, cowardly or not.

Also, there is a very direct link between gathering or not in groups and the spread of disease.

While one may make the argument that tracking individuals might be a tool to help with a ban on gathering of groups, the risk and history of those kinds of surveillance powers being abused, with no public benefit, and the lack of detail on both a plan on how that would be used (do we even have the capability of using that tracking information in a meaningful way) and what safeguards would be in place is a much more nebulous and less direct benefit/cost connection.

Comment: But there **is** a clear plan! China has proven that track and trace using mobile apps can be effective in bringing down the number of infections to zero, just as they have proven that lockdowns are effective. As for safeguards - what are the safeguards against governments capriciously banning public assembly? Presumably they'd all apply to surveillance as well.

Comment: @JonathanReez - China was able to lock down their citizenry in a way that non-totalitarian societies can not. Other countries have implemented very intensive testing regimes. That does not mean that the USA has the capability or a current plan to carry that out. China might already track their citizenry in such a way, independent of the application to disease vectors. If the USA lacks that capability, mechanisms, rules and/or plans, then how China does it is irrelevant. **China** has a clear plan. We are not China.

Comment: @JonathanReez - limitations on the ability to restrict public gathering is something that can be "turned off" as easily turned on, and use of that restriction is not easily concealed. The kind of infrastructure that needs to be in place for tracking individuals would not just be switched off because then you'd have to rebuild that infrastructure from scratch if you needed in a future, and the need would be time sensitive. I'm sorry, but I don't see the practical equivalence that matches up with the theoretical. They are very different, as is the track record in the types of restrictions.

Comment: For lockdowns, people presuppose that they're automatically effective and that the government had a clear plan on how to use them, without demanding evidence. Even though for example closing down national parks is on very shaky grounds as compared to shutting down kindergartens. Nor could they be instantly turned "off", as numerous businesses harmed by the forced closures will take many months to fully restore. In contrast, surveillance apps don't cause direct harm and could indeed be turned off with a click of a button.

Comment: @JonathanReez China has proven nothing, because we can't trust a thing they say.

Comment: @DM gyms are [open in China](https://mobile.twitter.com/ArjunKharpal/status/1247849477743861762). If they had a true pandemic this would be impossible. All thanks to apps and mass surveillance.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Your commentary about the efficacy of a "lockdown," which, again, would be very different in ability to implement in a more free vs restricted society, has no bearing on the question or answer. You are asking why people seem to be willing to give up one set of enumerated rights more readily than others. Governor declares "lockdown" and states what that means, then it's in place, effective or not. That's instantly turned "on." Governor declares lockdown is over, it's "off." How nimble society is to reacting to that does not change the status.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Actually all the physical infrastructure needed to do contact tracing of people who carry cell phones is already in place, and is necessary for the operation of the cell phone system.  All you'd need is some software, which is easily turned off.  Apps on individual phones would allow more detailed information to be collected, but there's no reason you have to have the app, or even carry a cell phone with you.

Comment: @jamesqf - but integrating the networks and the location data, in aggregate and the algorithms that would be necessary to identify potential gatherings and risky concentrations in an accurate and timely fashion are probably not in place. Think about the warrantless wiretapping they did under "W" Bush, and how any potentially useful information about wannabe terrorist shenanigans was lost in all the background signal noise, where it would take them so long to sift and identify that the opportunity for any useful action was long past.

Comment: @jamesqf - And I'm not talking about how easy it is to turn on and off, as much as how easy it would be to transparently verify that status at any particular time, and to see that it hasn't been switched on an off without proper controls and oversight.

Comment: Furthermore, restricting free movement of people and assembly thereof has a direct, measureable effect on the number of new infections: the less people meet, the smaller the number of newly infected. On the other hand, knowing every detail of your personal life (that what suspension of privacy utimately boils down to) does nothing to prevent the virus from spreading. The fact that Google knows more about us than our parents/partners/friends has no effect on spreading the virus by ourselves.

Comment: Hence, any potential benefit of surveilance is at best a secondary effect, if and only if, the data gathered by surveilance is put to practical use, i.e. isolating those identified as carriers of the virus. Thus, we are back to square one: restriction of freedom of movement. Surveillance is never a tool in its own right. Corona-surveillance is only as good as the measures that are triggered by the information.

Comment: @DohnJoe given that 50% of corona patients are asymptomatic, full compliance with tracking apps would be a HUGE deal. Now you'll get an instant notification on your phone if you've been in contact with a corona patient and would thus know to stay at home. Without the notification you would't even know you're infecting others.

Comment: @Jonathan exactly my point. If survellance is used to inform other processes, then it has value. Surveillance in itself is useless. I guess we can not compare lock-down measures with some corona apps, since a stay-home order is pretty straight forward, whereas some sort of corona app is way more involved. How are people tracked, is the data anonymized, how long is it stored, etc. Total can of worms. With a lock-down order, I don't even need to know who you are.

Comment: Lock-down is pretty binary: do you need to go out (essential work, getting food, etc.)? Whereas corona tracking is nowhere near being as easy question, since it all depends on the implementation. Installing an app is very intrusive, it's the digital equivalent of posting a police officer in each home. The officer might just check on the lock-down, or may go so far at to search my home. Is the location data only used to check on contact with identified carriers, or is it retained forever?

Comment: @DohnJoe its the exact same deal: in a lockdown you restrict people's rights by saying where they're allowed to go (essential work, pharmacy, food, hospital). In a surveillance solution you restrict people's right by saying *how* they're allowed to go out: only with an app broadcasting their beacon. Either both are okay or none are okay. In both approaches you don't have to do anything if you stay at home.

Comment: Maybe it's different. In a lock-down I can't go out. With surveillance, I have to hand over my data. The more I think about it, the more I am convinced that it is not entirely comparable. Lock-down is analogue, i.e. my physical presence is restricted in the physical space. This is very easy to grasp. Contact-tracing is digital, this is something which I have no control over, I don't see what it is doing, what it is sending. This feels very different to me. So maybe, it's simply the psychology of the masses.

Comment: I am ok with broadcasting my identity in the analogue space, e.g. by having licence plates on my car with a unique identifier. Yet, in the digital world, I would not be that relaxed, I like it to have different nick names in different online-places. Psychology: staying at home is easy; contact tracing is hard to understand. Does it equate to having licence plates on my car, or does it equate to being permantently followed and observed by a police officer? Different people will feel differently along this spectrum.

Comment: @JonathanReez - I didn't realize I had expressed any viewpoint, as opposed to explaining how I felt members of the public might differently perceive those two aspects.  But, okay.